# I am not able to write password of mysql in twrminal

Tags: mysql

I have downloaded mysql now opened terminal to run but it is not taking password.

[In the image it shows enter password but i am not able to write please give me solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjbnb.jpg)

It is not taking password but it shows enter password

Comment: It doesn't display the characters that you type, but you can still just type the password there and hit Enter.

Comment: What is 'twrminal'?

Answer (score 2):

terminals don't reflect passwords on screen and it confidential data just type the password and hit enter it will work..the password written will not be visible

Answer (score 0):

When entering passwords in the terminal, the characters you type won't be visible. Just type your password as you normally would and press Enter. Even though you don't see the characters, they are being entered.

if you are not able to type at all :

try to `ls -la /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql` to check permissions.

for me it shows :

> -r-x--x--x  1 root

if you do not have permissions, (you should be noticed the permission error) try to  `chmod +x /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`

then try again executing the command.

also try to pass the password directly in the CLI :

```
mysql -u root -p<password>
```